# Android: ViewProperty Animator is not working on 3.0 emulator

Tags: android, animation

I've used some Viewproperty animation in my application. Once it compile on android 3.0 tablet its working fine, if run on 3.0 emulator application crashes and its showing error on logcat.

**Code:**

```
ImageButton home = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.Home);
home.animate().setDuration(200);
smmslogo.animate().alpha(1);
```

**Error:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator.animatePropertyBy
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I think the crash is related to the bug at http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18803

Try using this call instead:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(home, "alpha", 0f, 1f).setDuration(200).start();
```